# In C#, how can I always treat a DateTime value as being local to Europe/London at the time represented by the DateTime, and convert this to UTC?

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone-offset

I am working with DateTime values in a SQL Server database I don't maintain, and I want to work with them in my code as UTC.

To assist in understanding the problem, the values I'm working with represent the time that actions took place in our CRM system.

When I retrieve the values from SQL Server, they have no time zone indication on them but I know that they always represent Europe/London - either UTC in the winter, or UTC+1 in the summer.

I understand that I can use DateTimeKind.Local to indicate that a DateTime value is expressed in local time, but I don't understand how I specify which time zone the DateTime applies to. For example, if I'm working with the DateTime `2021-01-01 12:34:56`, I need to ensure that regardless of where or when my code is running, this date is correctly interpreted as `2021-01-01 12:34:56 +00:00`. Equally, I need to ensure that regardless of where or when my code is running, I need to interpret `2021-05-01 12:34:56` as `2021-05-01 12:34:56 +01:00`.

How can I indicate that my DateTime values always apply to Europe/London at the time they represent?

Comment: One problem where you've got local datetime values without explicit timezone indicators is *ambiguous* values. I.e. the same local times occur twice on one of the DST transition days. There's no way to recover which one of them it was.

Comment: You can't.  In .NET `DateTime` alone is either `UTC`, `Undefined` or `Local` to the executing program's locale.  SQL Server's `datetime` doesn't even have that, which is why it's always loaded as `Undefined`. You *must* use `datetimeoffset` to preserve the timezone offset. If you want the timezone itself you have to store it explicitly

Comment: Why don't you use `DateTimeOffset` in your code and `datetimeoffset` in the database? If the timezone is always the same, what you ask for is effectively what you have right now: all `DateTime` values are assumed to be local. If you `need to ensure that regardless of where or when my code is running` though, you need to store the offset or timezone information

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever that's an interesting edge case I hadn't thought of, thank you. The solution suggested by Ygalbel works nicely if I use "AtLeniently".

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos unfortunately I can't change the database schema. My own code is using DateTimeOffset which is what has surfaced this problem. Using NodaTime as suggested below, I have been able to convert the SQL datetime values into DateTimeOffsets with the appropriate offset :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [nodaTime](https://nodatime.org/) is a powerful datetime library for C#.
The example in there homepage seems to be related to your case.

```
/ Instant represents time from epoch
Instant now = SystemClock.Instance.GetCurrentInstant();

// Convert an instant to a ZonedDateTime
ZonedDateTime nowInIsoUtc = now.InUtc();

// Create a duration
Duration duration = Duration.FromMinutes(3);

// Add it to our ZonedDateTime
ZonedDateTime thenInIsoUtc = nowInIsoUtc + duration;

// Time zone support (multiple providers)
var london = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["Europe/London"];

// Time zone conversions
var localDate = new LocalDateTime(2012, 3, 27, 0, 45, 00);
var before = london.AtStrictly(localDate);
```